# How can I keep the same Socket.id on different express routes?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm using Express, Spcket.io, Passportjs and ejs Mate for my project. A simple user to user chat app.

So the website's flow is, user logs in, index page is shown which has all the users, and once you click on any user a new page is shown in which user can chat to the other user.

The problem i'm having is that when user reaches the index page the socket starts the connection and a socket.id is generated, when the currentuser clicks on any user to chat with on the index page, a new socket connection starts and the socket.id changes, now if I go back to the index page, a new socket.id is generated. How can I keep the same socket.id on different pages?

I'm using express session

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
    }
};
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
```

but I can't seem to find a way to keep the same socket.id on all routes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the socket ID with the user's session. This way, when the user navigates between pages, the server can retrieve the socket ID from the session and use it to establish a connection with the existing socket.

UPDATE:
Update your session configuration to use the session middleware before the socket.io middleware.

```js
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
    }
})

app.use(sessionMiddleware)
```

add the sessionMiddleware to the Socket.io middleware to share the session data between Express and Socket.io

```js
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
})
```

In your route handling code, retrieve the socket.id from the request object's socket property

```js
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    const socketId = req.socket.id
     //or something like 
    const socketId = req.session.socketId
    // Use the socketId as needed
    // ...
})
```

Now when a user connects to your Express application using Socket.io, the session information will be shared between Express and Socket.io, and the socket.id will remain consistent across different routes as long as the user's session remains active.

```js
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {
  query: {
    socketId: //enter the target socket id here,
  },
})
```

Comment: I understand how I can save the Socket.id with the users, I am doing that and the private messaging works fine. But I don't understand how to re-connect to that same socket connection since on each page a new connection is created.

Comment: Sorry i realised that my answer wasn't really clear. I have updated my original answer. In my answer i am just trying to explain the idea. i am sure you can figure it out.